# IS NOT condition for rails instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash with members of an appointment and try to create a MySQL query in my rails controller.
The users with the ids from the map command e.g. {1,3} should be excluded in the query.
So for example @appointment.members.map{|m| m.user_id} returns {1,3,5} and I'd like to find all other users but these.

```
@users = User.where( "id NOT IN (?)", @appointment.members.map{|m| m.user_id} )
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.9 so maybe my exclude statement is wrong cause I don't get any result out of this query. The problem can't be the map array - I already tested that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error with the generated query?

Comment: Thats the strange part - if I test the query in the rails console I get valid results but in the controller the @users instance variable is empty...

Comment: Is `@appointment.members` really a Hash or do you mean that it's a `has_many` relationship?

Comment: it's a has_many relationship

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a problem with the `map` method, try this:

```
@users = User.where( "id NOT IN (?)", @appointment.members.map(&:user_id) )
```

EDIT: removed the wrong syntax for future readers if any

Comment: The first one returns just an empty array [], with the second one I get all users, including those in the .map array

Comment: The second one is not valid. The first one is

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a new instance variable:

```
@members = @appointment.members.all
```

and then

```
@add_users = User.where( "id NOT IN (?)", @members.map(&:user_id) )
```

thanks for the support

Comment: Then you can do `@add_users = User.where( "id NOT IN (?)", @appointment.members.all.map(&:user_id) )` directly, but you know that perhaps?